# Windows Application Creating Self-Dump

Tags: windows, debugging, crash

Codeproject has an article explaining how to [make your application provide a self-dump](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/postmortemdebug_standalone1.aspx) if it crashes.  I'd like to know what improvements, if any, have occurred to that technique (for Visual C++ 2008 and 2010).  I'd also like to know if the associated library, Dbghelp.dll, has limitations a developer should know about before investing in its use.

If that whole approach has been superceded by some other technique, do tell. :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [crashrpt](http://code.google.com/p/crashrpt/). Since its open source, and uses dbghelp.dll, you'll probabliy find relevant information in its source/doc.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Sysinternals [ProcDump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx) where you can save the dump easily with an unhandled exception occurs.

See this Channel9 [comment](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/10-4/10-4-Episode-34-Debugger-Enhancements-and-Improvements#c633927789660000000)